# HTML put 4 tables with different sizes side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-email, css-tables

I can't use div since this is for HTML Emails. I want to put multiple table with different height side by side, but that one table below doesn't take up the free space above. I am trying to achieve this using `<table>`:
[image]

But I am getting this instead:

[image]

This is currently my code:

```
<style>
   .textCenter {
        text-align: center;
   }
</style>

<body>

    <table width="48.5%" style="float:left">
    
        <tr>
            <td id="td1" class="textCenter">
    
            </td>
    
        </tr>
    
    </table>
    
    <table width="3%" height="20px" style="float:left">
        <tr width="100%">
            <td width="100%"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table width="48.5%">
        <tr>
            <td id="td2" class="textCenter">
            
            </td>
    
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table width="48.5%" style="float:left; top:20%">
        <tr>
            <td id="td3" class="textCenter">
    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table width="3%" height="20px" style="float:left">
        <tr width="100%">
            <td width="100%"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table width="48.5%" style="float:left">
    
        <tr>
            <td id="t4" width="44%" class="textCenter">
    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: You have 6 tables, but the picture has 4?

Comment: why cant you use `div`'s? They are supported for email-templates. create 2 wrapping div's for the 2 columns and use float or ìnline-block` to place them enxt to each other.

Comment: the 2 extra tables are irrelevant and only used for margin (since I don't want to use margin css for HTML emails.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables only approach. Floats are considered bad practice in most cases these days. Also, they just are messy to work with.

```css
.textCenter {
        text-align: center;
}
.wrapper table {border: solid 2px red;}
```

```html
<table class="wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top;">

      <table>
          <tr>
              <td id="td1" class="textCenter">
       Table 1
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

      <table>
          <tr>
              <td id="td3" class="textCenter">
      Table 3
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top;">

      <table>
          <tr>
              <td id="td2" class="textCenter">
              Table 2 <br />
              Table 2 <br />
              Table 2 <br />Table 2 <br />
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

      <table>
          <tr>
              <td id="t4" width="44%" class="textCenter">
      Table 4
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sir, you saved me many hours. I hope you have a great meal for tonight/today. Really appreciate it!

Comment: `float` are bad practice because nowadays you have flexbox and css-grid. However both are only supported to ~70% of the email-clients. Thats why within emai-tempaltes it is still acceptable practise to mis-use other tools such as tables and float for styling purpose.

Comment: @tacoshy flexbox is not read by Outlook. We have to code with older CSS.

Comment: @syfer, read my comment again. I said, both flexbox and css-grid are only supported to ~70%. Thats why float and tabels are both still acceptable practise for email-templates

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you separate the style logic from your html code.
I strongly encourage you to use flexbox css instead of `float properties`.
here is for example, the logic I apply to your code.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

table {
  width: 40%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 2px;
  }
  
  table tr td {
    text-align: center;
  }
  table.table1 {
    height: 12rem;
  }
  table.table2 {
    height: 21rem;
  }
  
  table.table3 {
    height: 16rem;
    position: relative;
      top: -9rem;
  }
  
  table.table4 {
    height: 7rem;
  }
```

```html
<body>

    <div>
      <table class="table1">
          <tr>
            <td id="td1" class="textCenter">
              table 1
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="table2">
          <tr>
            <td id="td2" class="textCenter">
              table 2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="table3">
          <tr>
            <td id="td3" class="textCenter">
              table 3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="table4">
          <tr>
            <td id="td4" class="textCenter">
              table 4
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This is for HTML email, most of which don't support `flex` and more advanced web standards

Comment: @Nathan, I notice that and I'm updating my response. Thank